# Populate dynamic table based on object data

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to populate the table by looping through the object. I am able to print the headers but not sure how to print the row values.

I am trying to populate the table as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

The definition of the object that I am trying to read is as follows

```
export interface NpvResults  {

        captiveInsYear: number[];
        captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
        captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
        captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
        captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
        captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
        captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];

    }
```

Hardcoded values in the component for testing purpose

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sourceResults = Object.assign({} as BackendDto.NpvResults) ;

    this.sourceResults.captiveInsYear = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this.sourceResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid = [-112000,568676,3343456,7676343,55656];
    this.sourceResults.captiveInsTaxDeduction = [44800,565656,347673,56565,34343];
    this.sourceResults.captiveInsLoanToParent = [0,3434,34346,5563,4545,343];
    this.sourceResults.captiveInsCapitalContribution = [0,347455,3435665,67676,34343];
    this.sourceResults.captiveDividentDistribution = [-2038328.6785651783,4545,4545,4545,56565];
    this.sourceResults.captiveInsTerminalValue = [0,5656,45454,23434,5656];

    }
```

Service method that gets the number of years to populate which is entered by the user in the previous screen. For e.g The user may enter 5 , 6 or 2 etc. The starting year would be the current year and if the user has entered 2 then only year 2018 and 2019 should be displayed on the screen. Hence the table would be dynamic.

The html table

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
       <p><span class="purple"></span>Captive</p>
       <table class="table">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th></th>
                         <th *ngFor= "let year of yearList"> {{year}}</th>
                         <th>Remaining Years</th>
                    </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                   <tr>
                      <td>Premium Paid</td>
                          <td>-30,339</td>
                          <td>-29,436</td>
                          <td>-28,559</td>
                          <td>-27,709</td>
                          <td>-26,884</td>
                          <td>0</td> 
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                            <td>Tax Deduction</td>
                            <td>12,136</td>
                            <td>11,774</td>
                            <td>11,424</td>
                            <td>11,084</td>
                            <td>10,754</td>
                            <td>0</td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Loan to Parent</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Capital Contribution/Distribution</td>
                          <td>-2,500</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>

                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>Dividened Distribution</td>
                          <td>na</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>

                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>Terminal Value</td>
                         <td>na</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>9,997</td>

                   </tr>                                            
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just

```
<td *ngFor="let item in sourceResults.captiveInsYear>{{2015+item}}</td>
<td *ngFor="let item in sourceResults.captiveInsPremiumPaid >{{item}}</td>
...
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand your logic. The year needs to be displayed under the Th tag. Do i need to do a ngFor for every td under tr.

Comment: @Tom, the only thing I want show it's that you must use *ngFor to "create" the table. I don't try to code for your concrete example, just an example